# Terraform: How to always generate a "fresh" EIP for new instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, elastic-ip

I have the following problem which I'm trying to solve with Terraform (0.11):

I have a couple of AWS EC2 instanced and Elastic IPs which are created with TF.
Now I need to create a **fresh** EIP in case an entirely new instance is created.

The reason is that as long as long as a machine is updated in place, the EIP can remain the same.
But is a new resource is required/created, the EIP **must not** be equal to the one attached to the old machine, because the content on the machine has changed then.

Does anyone have an idea how to generate these fresh EIPs in the case that a machine needs to be re-created?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
@ydaetskcoR I need an EIP in order to be able to stop and start the machine without having a new public IP attached to it, but if the instance is *replaced*, I need a new EIP.

@kenlukas The new instance would replace the old one:

```
resource "aws_eip" "master" {
  count = "${var.master_count}"
}

resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc_master" {
  count = "${var.master_count}"

  instance_id   = "${element(aws_instance.master.*.id, count.index)}"
  allocation_id = "${element(aws_eip.master.*.id, count.index)}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "master" {
  count = "${var.master_count}"

  subnet_id = ${element(var.public_subnet_ids, count.index)}"
  ...
}
```

This how it's done now, but I need to some sort of logic to generate new EIPS.
Is it maybe possible to trigger an AWS CLI request to delete the EIP associated to instance X, so that when Terraform is run, it will automatically generate a new one? Would work with a script which is triggered from within Terraform if an instance is missing?

Comment: Why are you using EIPs if you want to force new IPs? EIPs are specifically for keeping the IP address the same when changing the instance. What you seem to want is the default public IP address behaviour.

Comment: What's the process for removing the old server?  Is the new resource in addition to or instead of the current servers.  Show the code you're using to build out your current environment.

Comment: Please see my edit above ;)